# JAXB Bindings to schemas in a JAR

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, xjc, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I'm using the maven jaxb2 plugin to generate Java classes, built from schemas in a jar. However, I'm not sure how to correctly locate to these schemas from a bindings file. If Iextract the schemas from the jar and drop them in the same directory as the bindings, all is well. However, this isn't a practical long term solution.

pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
     <goals>
      <goal>generate</goal>
     </goals>
    </execution>
   </executions>
   <configuration>
    <schemas>
     <schema>
      <dependencyResource>
       <groupId>com.test</groupId>
       <artifactId>schemas</artifactId>
       <version>1.10-SNAPSHOT</version>
       <resource>schemas/schema.xsd</resource>
      </dependencyResource>
     </schema>
    </schemas>              
    <bindingDirectory>bindings</bindingDirectory>
    <generatePackage>test.package</generatePackage>
    <bindingIncludes>
     <include>*.xml</include>
    </bindingIncludes>
    <extension>true</extension>
   </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

bindings.xml:

```
<jxb:bindings xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb ./bindingschema_2_1.xsd"
 version="2.1">

<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="classpath:/schemas/schema.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
  <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='AbstractChangeable']">
   <jxb:class implClass="com.test.AbstractEntity" />
  </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I'd like to have working here is something like:

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="maven:org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin-tests-po!/purchaseorder.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package name="org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.tests.po"/>
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>      
</jaxb:bindings>
```

**But it does not** at the moment. Please [file an issue](http://java.net/jira/browse/MAVEN_JAXB2_PLUGIN), I'll try to fix it.

What does work now is SCD-based binding:

```
<jaxb:bindings scd="x-schema::po" xmlns:po="urn:po">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package name="org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.tests.po"/>
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>      
</jaxb:bindings>
```

So you don't actually need to bind based on a specific schema location, you can bind based on the namespace URI, which is theoretically better.

Practically I have an experience that SCD-bindings don't always work reliably.

**UPDATE**

See [this link](http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Using_SCD_for_customizations.html) for more information SCD usage in JAXB.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to use this SCB binding technique to refer to schemas inside of a maven provided dependency jar, are there examples?

Comment: I have posted the example above. You have to specify the namespace prefix (`xmlns:po="urn:po"`) and use this prefix in the scd expression (`scd="x-schema::po"` means "address the schema with the target namespace from prefix `po`"). See this link: http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Using_SCD_for_customizations.html

Comment: We didn't really understand how to reference a maven jar with that method, but we'll wait until the plugin is updated. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You don't need to reference a maven jar with this method. That is, you don't say "I refer to this element from this schema from this JAR". Instead you do binding via namespace, which is purely logical. What you express with SCD is "I refer to an element of the schema with the given namespace". No matter where the schema comes from. And please file an issue, otherwise I won't know who an why is interested in this functionality.

Comment: has this issue been fixed in the plugin - if you do not want to go the SCD based approach?

Comment: @Superaghu I don't remember fixing it.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use [`maven-dependency-plugin:unpack`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html) and then point `maven-jaxb2-plugin` to `outputDirectory`. In this case in binding file you need to say something like `schemaLocation="../target/schemas/schema.xsd"`

Comment: I've gotten that type of solution working already as mentioned, but I'd like to know how to reference schemas inside of a jar.

Comment: This does not work as unpack is tied to generate-resources goal and xjc runs in generate-sources goal which is earlier step

Comment: You could bind `unpack` to `generate-sources` phase (or earlier) as well. Any difficulties?

Comment: Thanks @dma_k - I bound it to `initialize` phase and able to get it to working

Answer (score -2):

I know this is an old question but I was struggling with the same problem. I found that doing inline bindings would solve the problem. You would no longer have any need for the binding file and the bindings would be carried over to projects depending on it.

Comment: Your answer would be much better with a code example.