# generate seriallized jaxb objects

Tags: maven-jaxb2-plugin

> I have read couple of post on how we can generate serilazed jaxb
>   objects i got the configuration

```
<jxb:bindings version="1.0"
 xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
 jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">

   <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="mirth.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
       <jxb:globalBindings>
           <xjc:superClass name="com.webreach.mirth.managers.types.MirthElement" />
                        <xjc:serializable />
       </jxb:globalBindings>
   </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

> As per my knowledge I cannot add this configuration in my POM.xml Can
>   anybody suggest me where i can add this configuration??

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you cannot add this jxb:bindings element into your pom.xml file. In the pom.xml you can define the maven-jaxb2-plugin that can refer to the bindings.xml file. You can find some helpfull material here

[JAXB Bindings to schemas in a JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506665/jaxb-bindings-to-schemas-in-a-jar)

http://mojo.codehaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/index.html

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply i will go through it.